# Php script to find path to a file

Tags: php, magento

We have a magento 1.9 instalation with custom pdf invoice template that has a logo inside. The function that calls that logo is:

```
$logoUrl = $this->getLogoUrl();
<img style="width: 100%;" src="<?php echo $logoUrl; ?>" alt="Logo">
```

how can i find out from console (ssh) the output of $this->getLogoUrl() ?

i need to replace that logo and i cannot find the file.

i tried the below statement but it outputs nothing:

```
<?php
$logoUrl = $this->getLogoUrl();
echo $logoUrl;
?>
```

Comment: hey, please try var_dump($logoUrl);

Answer (score 0):

Use

> Mage::log('', null, 'mylog.log', true);

Where  is what gets printed in your log file.
That should work all the time.

Note: that your logs should be open from the admin section